# At what points is given function differenciable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
-x^2, & x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\\ 
\end{cases}$$

At what points is $f$ differentiable

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Any guesses as to what the answer should be? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Me and my friends try finding limit when $x$ approaches to $c$ of $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, and separated it by cases when $x\in \mathbb{R}$ or $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} $ and same for $c$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** If $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ then $a$ is continuous at $x=a$. This will lead to a single potential value of $a$ where the function **could be** differentiable.

**Hint 2:** At any point where $f$ could be differentiable, us the definition of the derivative to check if $f$ is differentiable or not.

Comment: I guess you are saying that single potential value is $0$, because this function is continious only at $0$. But how to prove continuity at zero

Comment: @RushThaMan Yes. Note that for part 1 you don't need to prove the continuity at $x=0$, you need to prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $x \neq 0$!

Comment: How do you prove that?

Comment: @RushThaMan: Just use the following definition of continuity. If it is continuous at $x \neq 0$, then all sequences (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} converging to $x$ are such that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Could you find two sequences showing that this statement is wrong?

Comment: @RushThaMan If $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $x_n \to a$ then $f(x) \to f(a)$. Now pick $x_n$ rational, and then $x_n$ irrational.